# How to use std::bind properly with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, member, stdbind

I am trying to `std::bind` class functions in combination of `std::unique_ptr` and I have a lot of trouble getting it to work

First I have two classes

```
class simpleClass{
    public:
        simpleClass(int x){
            this->simpleNumber = x;
        }

        int simpleNumber;

        simpleClass(const simpleClass &toBeClone){
            this->simpleNumber = toBeClone.simpleNumber;
        }
        simpleClass clone(){
            simpleClass *cloned = new simpleClass(*this);
            return *cloned;
        }
};
```

```
class   className{
    public:
        className(doube input){
            this->someVariable = input;
        }

        void someFunction(std::vector<double> x, double c, std::unique_ptr<simpleClass> &inputClass, std::vector<double> &output){
            std::vector<double> tempOutput;
            for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++){
                tempOutput.push_back(x[i] + c * this->someVariable + inputClass->simpleNumber);
            }
            output = tempOutput;
        }

        double someVariable;

        className(const className &toBeClone){
            this->someVariable = toBeClone.someVariable;
        }

        className clone(){
            className *cloned = new className(*this);
            return *cloned;
        }
};
```

They are both some standard class, but I also implement a clone function to duplicate an initialized class. While cloning, I need to ensure that the original class and the cloned class points to different address. So I use `std::unique_ptr` to ensure this.

The is the main function, which also shows how I "clone"

```
int main(){
    className testSubject(5);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<className>> lotsOfTestSubject;

    simpleClass easyClass(1);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<simpleClass>> manyEasyClass;


    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        std::unique_ptr<className> tempClass(new className(testSubject.clone()))
        lotsOfTestSubject.push_back(std::move(tempClass));    

        std::unique_ptr<simpleClass> tempEasyClass(new simpleClass(easyClass.clone()))
        manyEasyClass.push_back(std::move(tempEasyClass));    
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<<double>> X; //already loaded with numbers
    double C = 2;
    std::vector<std::vector<<double>> OUT;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        std::vector<double> tempOUT;
        lotsOfTestSubject[i]->someFunction(X[i], C, manyEasyClass[i], tempOUT);
        OUT.push_back(tempOUT);

        //Here if I want to bind
        /*
           std::bind(&className::someFunction, lotsOfTestSubject[i], X[i], C, manyEasyClass[i], tempOUT);
        */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I "clone" is because both `simpleClass` and `className` takes a lot of time for construction in my implementation, and I need a lot of them. And Since many of them will be initialized with the same parameters, I figured this is the easiest way to do so.

The code above works, but I am trying to improve the speed of the loop. The following line is where most of the computation takes place.

```
lotsOfTestSubject[i]->someFunction(X[i], C, manyEasyClass[i], tempOUT);
```

So I am attempting to use threads to delegate the work , and as far as I know, I need to `std::bind` first. So I tried

```
std::bind(&className::someFunction, lotsOfTestSubject[i], X[i], C, manyEasyClass[i], tempOUT);
```

But the compiler prints error like this

```
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple|206|  recursively required from ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const _Head&, const _Tail& ...) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 1ul; _Head = std::vector<double>; _Tail = {double, std::unique_ptr<simpleClass, std::default_delete<simpleClass> >, std::unique_ptr<simpleClass, std::default_delete<simpleClass> >, std::vector<double>}]’|
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple|108|error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = className; _Dp = std::default_delete<className>]’|
```

I have no idea what this means as I just started self teaching c++. Any feedback and guidance is much appreciated.
I am using c++11 and g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

**Update**

Thanks @rafix07, tried your solution and it works fine. but then I tried to do

```
auto theBinded = std::bind(&className::someFunction, &lotsOfTestSubject[i], 
          X[i], C, std::ref(manyEasyClass[i]), tempOUT);
std::thread testThread(theBinded);
```

and eventually want to `testThread.join()`
But the compiler says

```
error: pointer to member type ‘void (className::)(std::vector<double>, double, std::unique_ptr<simpleClass>&, std::vector<double>&)’ incompatible with object type ‘std::unique_ptr<className>’|
```

@kmdreko Thanks for you point out! I haven't notice memory leak yet, but I will fix it. Do I just use this?

```
std::unique_ptr<className> tempClass = new className(testSubject);
```

Comment: Your `clone()` functions just call the copy constructor twice and leak memory; they are completely unnecessary. You should simply do `new className(testSubject)` since the copy constructor is the standard way to copy an object.

Comment: I edited my answer. I had a bug. Version with thread and join works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

If you want to call `someFunction` on instance stored in `lotsOfTestSubject` you need to pass pointer to `className` object on which this method will be called, so the line below

```
std::bind(&className::someFunction, lotsOfTestSubject[i]
```

should be replaced by:

```
auto theBinded = std::bind(&className::someFunction, lotsOfTestSubject[i].get(), 
                                                                          ^^^
```

Second change is to use `std::ref` to pass original instance of `unique_ptr` of `manyEasyClass` instead of its copy. `std::bind` always copies or moved its arguments ([see reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)), but `unique_ptr` is non-copyable, that is why compilation failed.

So fixed line looks:

```
auto theBinded = std::bind(&className::someFunction, lotsOfTestSubject[i].get(), 
      X[i], C, std::ref(manyEasyClass[i]), std::ref(tempOUT));
```

`tempOUT` also must be passed by `std::ref` because you want to modify this vector by call operator() on functor created by `bind`.

[LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/-25M05)

Comment: Thanks @rafix07 , your solution compiled! I will play around with this and understand better.